# AudioUnit generating noise with 8000 Sample rate. Xamarin.ios (Monotouch)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, core-audio, audiounit

I am using `AudioUnit` class for recording and playback. During recording i can listen sound. Problem is that when i use sample rate `44100` then it working fine but if i use sample rate `8000` then it generating noise. After recording with `8000` sample rate when i play then there is no noise, there is actual sound.
Means only the time of recording it generate noise with actual sound.

My AudioStreamBasicDescription setting is-

```
audioStreamDescription.Format = AudioFormatType.LinearPCM;
audioStreamDescription.FormatFlags = AudioFormatFlags.LinearPCMIsSignedInteger |
                                                      AudioFormatFlags.LinearPCMIsPacked;
audioStreamDescription.SampleRate = 8000; // 44100;
audioStreamDescription.BitsPerChannel = 16;
audioStreamDescription.ChannelsPerFrame = 1;
audioStreamDescription.BytesPerFrame = (16 / 8);
audioStreamDescription.FramesPerPacket = 1;
audioStreamDescription.BytesPerPacket = audioStreamDescription.BytesPerFrame * audioStreamDescription.FramesPerPacket;
audioStreamDescription.Reserved = 0;
```

AudioUnit setting is-

```
public void prepareAudioUnit()
{
    // Getting AudioComponent Remote output 
    _audioComponent = AudioComponent.FindComponent(AudioTypeOutput.Remote);

    // creating an audio unit instance
    audioUnit = new AudioUnit.AudioUnit(_audioComponent);

    // turning on microphone
    audioUnit.SetEnableIO(true, AudioUnitScopeType.Input, 1 );

    audioUnit.SetEnableIO(true, AudioUnitScopeType.Output, 0 );

    // setting audio format        
    var austat = audioUnit.SetFormat(audioStreamDescription, AudioUnitScopeType.Output, 1);

   var austatInput = audioUnit.SetFormat(audioStreamDescription, AudioUnitScopeType.Input, 0);

   //audioUnit.SetSampleRate(8000.0f, AudioUnitScopeType.Output, 0);
   //audioUnit.SetSampleRate(8000.0f, AudioUnitScopeType.Input, 1);

  // setting callback method
  audioUnit.SetRenderCallback(render_CallBack, AudioUnitScopeType.Input, 0);

  audioUnit.Initialize();
}
```

Now, my main question is how i can remove that noise which is comming with actual sound? 
If i am not able to explain properly then please let me know.

Comment: I have only limited AU experience, but my guess is you aren't actually recording at 8kHz, but rather at 44.1kHz.  Did you set the preferred sample rate on the AVAudioSession correctly?

Comment: Hello Tim, I did. Here is my session code- 
bool preferredSampleRateResult = avAudioSessionObj.SetPreferredSampleRate(8000.0f, out errorRes);